# Incompatible pointer- MPMoviePlayer from URL

Tags: ios, pointers, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I have an NSArray that loads video files from XML data. When you press an Array item, it loads a view with a button that should load the NSString url. Here's the code I'm working with.

```
-(IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender
    {
        RSSItem* item = (RSSItem*)self.description;
        NSURL *movieUrl = [NSURL URLWithString: item];
        MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieUrl];
        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
        moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
        [moviePlayerController play]; 
    }
```

I am getting the warning "Incompatible pointer types sending 'RSSItem *_strong' to parameter of type 'NSString *'

I have tried everything that I can think of to convert the string to a string and get it to work.  Please let me know if this question is too specific or basic for the forum.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

`RSSItem* item = (RSSItem*)self.description;`

should be this:

`NSString* item = self.description;`

The above line in your code is puzzling and troubling.  Why are you trying to cast `description` (which is an `NSString` to begin with) to an `RSSItem`?

Comment: That fixed the warning. I'm still having trouble passing a url, but I need to figure out what my project has going on before I do that. I am not very good at passing data, and am using RaptureXML to parse an xml feed, so I need to figure out how to extract individual strings of data.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Make sure to pay attention to what @rmaddy said!

Comment: I now switched it to a load a different property (a NSURL) and now my NSLog is returning null for the NSURL.


    `NSURL* item = self.link;
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:item];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    NSLog(@"url = %@",item);
    moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
    [moviePlayerController play];`


Do you see anything here, or would the problem be from the instance that it's being created?

Answer (score 1):

The `NSURL URLWithString:` method expects a parameter of type `NSString`. But you are passing some unknown `RSSItem` object. You need to pass an `NSString`.

Why are you casting `self.description` to an `RSSItem`? The `description` method is a standard method from `NSObject`. It returns an `NSString`.

If you have added your own `description` method to your class you really should rename it. The `description` method already has a specific purpose.

If you are using the standard `description` method then this is a bad use for it. The `description` method should never be used for anything except for debugging.

Comment: Thanks! This helps me understand the logic behind the solution better.